# Search for pattern and print pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find, ksh

I want to search for a pattern, then print that pattern. I have found grep -o would be the best option, but I don't have that available. I can use sed, grep, or awk.

**Output:** find: cannot chdir to `</home/test/.ssh>`: Permission denied

I want to match pattern "/home/test" and return "/home/test/.ssh" and ignore the rest of the line.

I've tried:

```
find /home/test 2>&1 | sed -n '/\/home\/test\/.ssh/ s/.*\(\/home\/test\/.ssh\).*/\1/p'
```

But this replaces all matches with /home/test

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just `find /home/test -name '.ssh'`?

Comment: @Sobrique I am trying to account for stderr. I don't think that would work because I want to find everything in /home/test. If the output contains my output example above, I only want to print the path.

Comment: An example of what you are trying to output would be a good idea then.

Comment: @Sobrique sorry, I've edited the post now. You should be able to see the output of the find command. Basically if find returns an error, I want to extract the path it cant access.

Comment: Ah, now that's a somewhat different thing! Does it have to be find?

Comment: @Sobrique I think find works best because I can give it the top most directory, and it will return everything under it. I've tried using ls -R it doesn't work as well

Comment: Actually, no. I've just reread your question. What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish here? A "find" that ignores errors? Or a find operation that only reports errors?

Comment: What you want to do is trivial. We just don't know what that IS yet :-). Edit your question to include concise, testable, sample input and expected output so we can start trying to help you.

Comment: @Sobrique I'm looking for a "find" that if it encounters an error, it can extract the "path" from the error. If "find" returns find: cannot chdir to </home/test/.ssh>: Permission denied , I want to extract "/home/test/.ssh" from the error and print it.

Comment: But do you want to keep the original output of `find`? I mean, you could just redirect `STDOUT` and catch `STDERR` instead.

Comment: @Sobrique yes, I'd like to capture both STDOUT & STDERR, Even if I capture only STDERR, I will get the full error line. I just want to extract the path from the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `find` printing an error for "things you can't access" that's a slightly different scenario. `find` prints to "STDERR" when that happens. So you can just:

```
find /home/test 2>&1 1>/dev/null
```

This will just print the errors you hit with your find. If you still need to 'clean up' the permission denied error, if `grep -o` is what you're after, you can probably do it in `perl`:

```
 find /home/test 2>&1 1>/dev/null | perl -ne 'print m,<(.*)>,'
```

(assuming your output from `find` has the path in `<>`)

Comment: That works great! Is there anyway to separate the output into new lines instead of singe lined?

Comment: Yes. `perl -ne 'print m,<(.*)>, ,"\n"'`